# Can photos of the Mount Olympus be used commercially?

Tags: european-union, photography

I have heard that some European countries restrict commercial use of protected archeological or cultural heritage items. But this does affect natural settings like the mount Olympus (located in Greece) as well?

Comment: Never heard of anything like that. Can you give a link/quote?

Comment: @PMF This applies to certain European countries. Italy is one of them (they have a law known as the "Cultural Heritage and Landscape Code" that restricts commercial use of cultural heritage items, including when such items are depicted in photography).

Comment: Then it seems nobody really cares. At least I can't see any related remarks in the pictures in [this category](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Forum_Romanum). And commons is usually very picky about such restrictions, even if they don't affect copyright.

Comment: You'd have to get a license from Zeus to use the image commercially.

Comment: I believe this has generally shown up largely from museums attempting to commercialize their collections, most often of paintings.  I think I heard something about the Louvre attempting to do this with the Mona Lisa or some such.  Despite the fact that the painting has long been in the public domain...

Comment: This discusses the Greek Cultural heritage law  which does not apply to natural features, although natural features could conceivably be covered by another law. https://www.law-archaeology.gr/index.php/en/greek-cultural-herutage-law